# How to import methods from class instantiation in python?

Tags: python, class, methods

I want to create an instantiation of a class and call the methods of the instantiation without the syntax `I.method`. Instead, I want to call it as just `method`. Is this possible? If so how? A concrete example for how I want to do this this is below.

The motivation for this is that, in this particular instance, the code will look cleaner and also just faster to write. (`warn()` is faster to write than  `logger.warn()`)

I am using logger to logger errors and warnings:

```
import logging
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger('__main__') #only report main logs
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) #put to standout
logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.warn('This is a warning')
logger.info('this is just info')
```

Writing `logger` (or whatever it is instantiated as) is annoying.
I want to be able to do something like this:

```
import logging
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger('__main__') #only report main logs
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) #put to standout
logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
#Magic line of code

warn('This is a warning') #not logging.warn
info('this is just info')
```

However, I can't just do something like this

```
from logging import *
warn('this is a warning')
```

Since this will not instantiate the logging class in the way I want (e.g. only report main logs and print to sys.stdout.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can configure the root logger using `basicConfig`, which would do everything except make the root logger named `__main__`. That may not be necessary, or you might try *replacing* the root logger with `logger`.

Comment: That said, anyone else reading your code is probably going to expect `warn` et al. to operate on the "standard" root logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign names to methods.

Example:

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute

    def method(self, prefix):
        print(prefix, self.attribute)

mine = Class('Only A Plank Between One And Perdition')
free_function = mine.method
free_function('And I Say,')
```

Output:

```
And I Say, Only A Plank Between One And Perdition
```

In your case, you want `warn = logger.warn`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a workaround, but you could create the following file logger.py :

```
import logging
import sys

class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('__main__') #only report main logs
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) #put to standout
    self.logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    self.logger.addHandler(handler)

def warn(message):
    logger = Logger()
    return logger.logger.warn('This is a warning')
```

from there you can just import the warn function:

```
from logger import warn

warn('This is a warning')
```

If you don't want to to recreate the logger object every time you want to issue a warning, you could pass it as an argument to the warn function.

Comment: This is  clever, but I selected gmds's answer because it is more straightforward